# Changing CSS from Angular Material Checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

can someone tell me, how I can change the colour of the round circle when you click the angular material checkbox. Shown in the following image (the pink circle)

[image]

Here is the link from the official webpage: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Thanks for the Help

Comment: This round circle  is called **`ripple`**. Do you want to change the color of only on the checkbox ripple or all the ripples in the app? Or do you want to disable the ripple altogether?

Comment: actually, I want to change all ripple effects in the app. the earlier post helped me with changing the checkbox ripple `.green-checkbox {
  .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: $darkgreen !important;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}`
i dont know, why its been deleted

Comment: @Peter I deleted my post because for some reason it was being downvoted. If it helped you, I will undelete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The checkbox (both the checkmark and the ripple), by default uses the `accent` color from your theme. You can change it to use the primary color by using the `color = "primary"` property on the element. If you want to use a custom color *(i.e. not from the theme)*, you'd have to override the CSS manually or [create a custom theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

If you only want to override the color of the ripple, you can override the `.mat-ripple-element` class which is added on the generated ripple element whenever you click the checkbox. Add your desired styles to `theme.scss`.

```
.custom-ripple {
  .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: rgba(100, 200, 50, 0.5) !important;
  }
}
```

[Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pjhvgs).