# How to make a round checkbox with angular-material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

My code is pretty simple

```
<mat-checkbox
  [(ngModel)]="checked"
  [color]="'primary'"
></mat-checkbox>
```

How can I make this material checkbox round? I have tried setting the style `border-radius: 50%`on pretty much all tags generated by Angular under this element but the most I have achieved is a round 'selected' look inside a rectangle.

I am sure there is a better way. I have found [this answer about reusing the graphics of a radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332350/how-to-make-a-circle-checkbox-with-material-ui) but I have been unable to adapt it to my case (dont even know where to start)

Comment: You need to override its default CSS

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Changing CSS from Angular Material Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791458/changing-css-from-angular-material-checkbox)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend styling a checkbox to look like a radio button. it will just confuse the users

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-3nh8z5 working

Comment: Thank you Prashant - this is exactly what I was looking for. Hopefully it will still work with the latest angular materials version, will give it a try tomorrow. If you create a response to the question, I would accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is created based on the comment posted by Prashant Pimpale as he did not create an answer himself. Stackblitz is updated to latest version of libraries at time of writing this.

HTML

```
<mat-checkbox color="primary">Regular checkbox</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox class="custom-frame">Circular checkbox</mat-checkbox>
```

SCSS

```
::ng-deep .custom-frame {
  & .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-radius: 70% !important;
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-kuztkp

Comment: Just for reference for others, ng-deep, >>>, /deep/ usage is deprecated. See [this doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). So, beware. Although, I should also add that this has been deprecated (but not removed) for more than 3 years now.

Comment: it will forever be deprecated but not removed because the angular team can't just let us style them without needing ng-deep or making the style global by putting it in styles.css